# REACT - Iterate through Json object with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am currently fetching a json Object from the following sample URL:
https://demo0046512.mockable.io/stream/anycontent

My purpose is to iterate trough each array ("zone") and make a switch-case which will call different methods depending on the `type` fields

I tried looking at this other similar case [Iterating over JSON in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309300/iterating-over-json-in-react)
but I am still struggling with iterating trough the json Object correctly, what am I not doing properly?

Here's the iteration code:

```
interpretJson(jsonObj){

    if(jsonObj){    
      var arr = [];
      Object.keys(jsonObj).map((zone, index) => {
          arr.push(jsonObj[zone]);
          }) 
      return(
        <div>
        <p> interpretJson output: </p>
          <ul>
            {arr.map(item => {
                item.type
              }) 
            }
          </ul>
        </div>  
      )
    }
  }
```

Displaying the output is only meant to see if it is being iterated correctly, so I can proceed to the switch case, but apparently something is not right.

Comment: because you are not returning anything inside map body use this: `{arr.map(item => 
                <li>item.type</li>
              )}`

Comment: tried that and <li>{item.type}</li> but it is still not printing the types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the zones object keys and then into the zone1 and zone2 array to collect the diffrent types and after that remove the duplicates.

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "zones":{    
        "zone1":[
            {"type": "text", "url": "http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH", "displaytime": "15"},      
            {"type": "image", "url": "http://i.imgur.com/FuD18KJ.jpg", "displaytime": "10"},
            {"type": "video", "url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" }
        ],
        "zone2":[
            {"type": "text", "url": "http://pastebin.com/raw/1U5vhVzH", "displaytime": "16"},      
            {"type": "image", "url": "http://i.imgur.com/FuD18KJ.jpg", "displaytime": "11"},
            {"type": "video", "url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" }
        ]
    }
}

      var arr = [];
      Object.keys(jsonObj.zones).forEach((zone, index) => {
              jsonObj.zones[zone].forEach((obj, idx) => {
                  arr.push(obj.type)
              })
          })
          
     arr = arr.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i) // remove duplicate entries
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That's completely correct sir. So my problem was that I was passing a group of inner objects at a time with jsonObj[zone] instead of one by one?

Comment: Glad it helped you