# How to iterate through JSON data and dynamically create and populate components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to React and JSX and have created a component which displays a title and image which will serve all as a link. I would now like to set the title and image by iterating through JSON data (currently my JSON is accessible via a locally defined variable).

I would like to know how to dynamically create and populate the components with the appropriate data. My code currently looks like this:

```
<script>
        var RecipeList = React.createClass({
                const items = [
                    {
                        id: 2234567,
                        title: "Fried Chicken",
                        image-url: "https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/4577069.jpg",
                        ingredient: ["Chicken", "Flour", "Eggs", "Salt", "Pepper"]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2234567,
                        title: "Grilled Chicken",
                        image-url: "https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/4577069.jpg",
                        ingredient: ["Chicken", "Olive oil", "Salt", "Pepper"]
                    }
                ]
                getDefaultProps: function() {
                  return {items: []}  
                },
                render: function() {
                    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
                       return(
                            <div className="container-fluid">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="recipeContainer col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                        <h3 className="recipeTitle">{this.props.title}</h3>
                                        <div className="recipeImage">
                                            <img src="{this.props.image}" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="recipeBtn">See recipe</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    });

                    return (
                        {listItems}
                    );
                 }
            });

ReactDOM.render(
                <div>
                    <IngredientList></IngredientList>
                    <RecipeList items={items}></RecipeList>
                    <RecipeSection></RecipeSection>
                </div>
                , document.getElementById("module"));
        </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicated question [Iterate Over JSON in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309300/iterating-over-json-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by passing the JSON data into the `items` prop of your `<RecipeList />` so that this data is used to dynamically render the component via that data.

Additionally, there are a few other things to update to get this to work:

1. you'll want to fix the format of your input JSON so that item keys are either wrapped with quotes, or don't have hyphens.
2. ensure you're accessing data from the `item` in `map()` when rendering the list items, rather than accessing the item data from `this`
3. wrap the list items that you're rendering with a "root element" at the `return` line of your `render()` method. A simple solution is to usually wrap the return result with a `<div>`, however with more recent versions of React you can use `<React.Fragment>` (this allows you to return multiple elements in a `render()` result, without adding the extra "div element" to be resulting DOM).

Here's a working snippet:

```html
<div id="module"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script type="text/babel">

  /*
  Use class to define component using React16
  */
  class RecipeList extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
    
      var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
        return(
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="recipeContainer col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <h3 className="recipeTitle">{item.title}</h3> { /* <-- Corrected this to use item.title */ }
                <div className="recipeImage">
                  <img src={item.image} /> { /* <-- Corrected this to use item.image */ }
                </div>
              <div className="recipeBtn">See recipe</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    
    /*
    When rendering multiple DOM elements as a list, you
    must wrap these with React.Fragment, or something else
    like a div
    */
    return (<React.Fragment>{listItems}</React.Fragment>);
    }
  };

  /*
  Declare items data array which will passed to the items
  prop of the <RecipeList> component
  */
  const items = [{
      'id': 2234567,
      'title': "Fried Chicken",
      'image': "https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/4577069.jpg",
      'ingredient': ['Chicken', 'Olive oil', 'Salt', 'Pepper']
  },
  {
      'id': 2234567,
      'title': "Grilled Chicken",
      'image': "https://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/4577069.jpg",
      'ingredient': ['Chicken', 'Olive oil', 'Salt', 'Pepper']
  }];

  ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        { /* Pass the items data array to the items prop */ }
        <RecipeList items={items}></RecipeList>
      </div>, 
  document.getElementById("module"));
</script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated the code however there still is no output showing

Comment: @S.Miller just updated answer and code snippet with a few other fixes - does this help?

Comment: I can't get it to display yet but I see your example works perfectly. Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.

Comment: @S.Miller just updated the answer again with a bit more detail - glad I could help! :)

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to create just the "recipeContainer" divs rather than the entire component? So that each item stays within the bootstrap grid?

Comment: Yup , if I understand your question, then just move the `<div className="container-fluid">` out of the component `render()` method, and into the `ReactDOM.render( .. )` method so that it wraps ` <RecipeList />`