# Getting items from object within JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to create a React component that displays results from a test in various courses. I'm unable to access the scores object within the json file. Here is a sample of the json file I'm working with.

```
[
    {
    "length": "15",
    "average": "77",
    "created_at": "2019-02-01",
    "course": "MATH311",

    "scores": [
      {
        "correct": "12",
        "student_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "correct": "9",
        "student_id": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "length": "25",
    "average": "17",
    "created_at": "2019-02-03",
    "course": "MATH301",

    "scores": [
      {
        "correct": "11",
        "student_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "correct": "17",
        "student_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "correct": "20",
        "student_id": "5"
      },
      {
        "correct": "18",
        "student_id": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From this, I want to create a component that displays a card for each exam and contains the "course", "average", "length", and each of the scores. I can get the course, average, and length but cannot get every score because it's an object of its own. The number of scores will vary.

My code looks something like this.

```
<div className="exams">
{exams && exams.map((exam,index) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>{exam.course}</p>
            <p>{exam.average}</p>
            <p>{exam.length}</p>
            <div>
              {exam["scores"][0].id}
              {exam["scores"][0].correct}
            </div>

        </div>
    )
})}
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code where you have attempted to iterate the `scores`.

Comment: can you try exam["scores"][0].id, if you want all the scores, you have to iterate

Comment: Looks like you have to iterate and then map, see if this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309300/iterating-over-json-in-react

Answer (score 1):

As Scores is an array and not an object, use `map` to iterate over all entries of scores. Like this:

```
  <div className="exams">
    {exams && exams.map((exam,index) => { return(
    <div>
        <p>{exam.course}</p>
        <p>{exam.average}</p>
        <p>{exam.length}</p>
        <div>

            {exam && exam["scores"] && exam["scores"].map((score,index) => { return(
            <div>
                {score.correct} {score.student_id}

            </div>
            ) } )}
        </div>

    </div>
    ) })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`exam.scores` is an array. With javascript you can iterate over it with map, generating a jsx element for each item in `exam.scores` just like you already did for the exams array. The code may look like this

```
<div>
    {exam.scores.map(score => {
        return(
            <div key={score.student.id}>
                <p>score: {score.correct}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }}
</div>
```

You need to make sure that each child element has a unique key value when you map over an array.

Answer (score 0):

Scores are not an object, they are an array. So you have to `map` over them just as you did with the exams.

```
  exams.map((exam, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <p>{exam.course}</p>
      <p>{exam.average}</p>
      <p>{exam.length}</p>
      {exam.scores.map((scores, i) => (
        <div key={scores.student_id}>
          <p>{scores.correct}</p>
          <p>{scores.student_id}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: exams.scores(inner map call) will be undefined and you should add a key property to the wrapping div in the inner map function. Hence the down vote

Comment: {exams.scores.map((scores, i) => will still be undefined. It should be {exam.scores.map((scores, i) - remove s from exams. And <div key={score.student.id}> is also undefined, it should be <div key={scores.student_id}>. Sorry for being so narrow :D

Comment: exam.map((exam, index) => should be exams.map((exam, index) => (
<div key={scores.student.id}> should be  <div key={scores.student_id}>