# Mapping through multiple nested objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am working on a simple project in React and being new in React I was having trouble in mapping through the given json file to send required objects to different components.

This is what JSON file I have been given(through api)

```
{
   "trees":{
      "name":"a",
      "age":"9",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },
   "cars":{
      "name":"b",
      "age":"30",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },
   "bikes":{
      "name":"c",
      "age":"110",
      "height":"10",
      "location":"park"
   },.........................
```

This is the json which I am fetching in App.js. My idea is to send this completely to another component(Data.js) then from data.js to another component which will have trees, cars, bikes .
I am not able to map through this json file at any level even after doing `const d = [jsonfile]` even after this I get undefined while mapping.

App.js

```
const[Data,setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('API-HERE').then((result)=>{result.json().then((resp)=>{
      setData(resp); 
    })})
  },[])

return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataFetched data={Data} />
    </div>
  );
```

After this I am unable to map in DataFetched.js to send it to another child only trees cars bikes seprately so that their attributes can be read.

Comment: Do you want to send them as a flat array to `DataFetched` component?

Comment: Yes, And from DataFetched to child such that I can read trees,cars,bikes seperately in that child...So that in that child I can use like `trees.name` etc..

Comment: what do you mean by mapping? can you write an example of a mapped data? basically, you should write a loop too read data and render same component for each index

Comment: `const samplerecipes = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Pasta",
  cookingTime: 90,
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Curry",
  cookingTime: 40,
}]`

Comment: Duplicate question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309300/iterating-over-json-in-react`

Comment: If the above is the json then I can do sampleRecipes.map(recipe => return <DataFetched {...recipe} ) />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over JSON in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309300/iterating-over-json-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` iterate over the `JSON` properties.

You can try like this.

```
import React from "react";

const DataFetched = ({ data }) => {
    if (!data) {
        return null;
    }
    return Object.entries(data).map(
        ([key, { name, age, height, location }]) => {
            return (
                <div key={key}> 
                    <div>{name}</div>
                    <div>{age}</div>
                    <div>{height}</div>
                    <div>{location}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    );
};

export default DataFetched;
```

Or you can receive the data from another child component.

```
import React from "react";

const MyChildComponent = ({ data: { name, age, height, location } }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{age}</div>
            <div>{height}</div>
            <div>{location}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

const DataFetched = ({ data }) => {
    if (!data) {
        return null;
    }
    return Object.entries(data).map(
        ([key, value]) => {
            return (
                <MyChildComponent data={value}/>
            );
        }
    );
};

export default DataFetched;
```

Comment: Thanks .. but the problem is there is 100s of objects like trees cars so It wont be feasible to make cases for all of them also I want to have a single child only for trees cars ..... and not multiple child like <trees/> <cars/>

Comment: I got you. I will update the answer

Comment: Can you help me by telling me how to receive this data in my child component?

Comment: @VATSAL JAIN, You can pass the data to another component. Updated the answer.